# Extracting substring from PDF raw text using regex

Tags: python, regex, text, regex-lookarounds, data-processing

I was trying to extract the subsection that has the roman indexing from a pdf document.

For instance this is one section of the document,

> \n1.1\n \nSCOPE\n \nThis PTS specifies the\n \nrequirements \nand recommendations for Classification, Verification \n\nFunct\nions.\n \nThe scope includes the following:\n \ni.\n \nSemi\n-\nquantitative SIL classification\n \nii.\n \nSpurious trip analysis\n \niii.\n \nProbabilistic and architectural SIL verification\n \niv.\n \nRecommendations\n \nfor SIL gap closure'

what I want is only below:

> This PTS specifies the\n \nrequirements \nand recommendations for Classification, Verification \n\nFunct\nions.\n \nThe scope includes the following:\n \ni.\n \nSemi\n-\nquantitative SIL classification\n \nii.\n \nSpurious trip analysis\n \niii.\n \nProbabilistic and architectural SIL verification\n \niv.\n \nRecommendations\n \nfor SIL gap closure

I need the sentence before the roman indexing as well as the content inside roman indexing.

However, there are also cases like below

> 3.1.3\n \nDo\nc\numentation\n \nrequired\n \nT\nh\ne\n \nl\nat\ne\ns\nt\n \nissue\n \nof\n \nt\nh\ne\n \nf\no\nllo\nw\ni\nng\n \ndocume\nn\nts\n \nshall\n \nbe\n \nav\na\nilab\nl\ne\n \nto\n \nthe\n \nte\na\nm\n \np\ne\nrf\no\nrm\ni\nng\n \nt\nh\ne \nc\nl\nass\ni\nf\ni\ncati\no\nn:\n \ni.\n \nMandatory reference document\n \na)\n \nCause and effect matrices (CEM)\n \nb)\n \nPiping and Instrument Diagram (P&ID) or Process and utility engineering \nflow schemes (PEFS)\n \nc)\n \nHAZOP report\n \nd)\n \nIPF reliability data\n \nii.\n \nOther reference document\n \na)\n \nProcess Flow Diagram (PFD) or Process Fl\now Scheme (PFS)\n \nb)\n \nPlant layout drawing\n \nc)\n \nProcess safeguarding flow schemes (PSFS)\n \nd)\n \nControl narratives\n \ne)\n \nInterlocks/ ESD logic diagram\n \nf)\n \nEquipment layout diagram\n \ng)\n \nMaintenance and Inspection Data\n \nh)\n \nPlant historian data\n \n \nT\nh\ne\n \nl\ni\ns\nt\n \na\nb\no\nve\n \nis\n \nn\no\nt\n \ne\nx\nh\na\nu\nsti\nv\ne. Any\n \not\nh\ne\nr\n \ndo\nc\nu\nm\ne\nn\nt\ns\n/ \nd\nr\na\nw\nin\ng\ns\n \nreq\nu\nir\ne\nd\n \nf\no\nr\n \nt\nhe \nc\nom\np\nletion\n \no\nf the\n \nIPF\n \ns\nt\nu\nd\ny\n \ns\nh\na\nll\n \nbe\n \nf\nu\nr\nn\nished\n \nas\n \na\nn\nd\n \nw\nhen\n \nre\nq\nui\nr\ne\nd\n.\n \n

I've converted the pdf into raw text and I've managed to extract section of the document. The

```
regx = re.compile( '\.\n \n.+?:\n \n',re.DOTALL)
find = str(txt)
indexhead.append((regx.findall(find)))
```

The above code can only extract the headline but not the roman indexing together

> .\n \nThe scope includes the following:\n \n

I'm trying to extract based on the pattern but I'm thinking maybe some conditional rules might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem right, we would want to just take out the roman indices, and get the entire paragraph, which we would start with a simple expression such as:

```
.+[0-9]\.?.+?([A-Z][a-z].*)
```

then as new cases come up, we would just use logical ORs and add additional rules.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cx8rpV/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r".+[0-9]\.?.+?([A-Z][a-z].*)"

test_str = ("\\n1.1\\n \\nSCOPE\\n \\nThis PTS specifies the\\n \\nrequirements \\nand recommendations for Classification, Verification \\n\\nFunct\\nions.\\n \\nThe scope includes the following:\\n \\ni.\\n \\nSemi\\n-\\nquantitative SIL classification\\n \\nii.\\n \\nSpurious trip analysis\\n \\niii.\\n \\nProbabilistic and architectural SIL verification\\n \\niv.\\n \\nRecommendations\\n \\nfor SIL gap closure'\n\n"
    "3.1.3\\n \\nDo\\nc\\numentation\\n \\nrequired\\n \\nT\\nh\\ne\\n \\nl\\nat\\ne\\ns\\nt\\n \\nissue\\n \\nof\\n \\nt\\nh\\ne\\n \\nf\\no\\nllo\\nw\\ni\\nng\\n \\ndocume\\nn\\nts\\n \\nshall\\n \\nbe\\n \\nav\\na\\nilab\\nl\\ne\\n \\nto\\n \\nthe\\n \\nte\\na\\nm\\n \\np\\ne\\nrf\\no\\nrm\\ni\\nng\\n \\nt\\nh\\ne \\nc\\nl\\nass\\ni\\nf\\ni\\ncati\\no\\nn:\\n \\ni.\\n \\nMandatory reference document\\n \\na)\\n \\nCause and effect matrices (CEM)\\n \\nb)\\n \\nPiping and Instrument Diagram (P&ID) or Process and utility engineering \\nflow schemes (PEFS)\\n \\nc)\\n \\nHAZOP report\\n \\nd)\\n \\nIPF reliability data\\n \\nii.\\n \\nOther reference document\\n \\na)\\n \\nProcess Flow Diagram (PFD) or Process Fl\\now Scheme (PFS)\\n \\nb)\\n \\nPlant layout drawing\\n \\nc)\\n \\nProcess safeguarding flow schemes (PSFS)\\n \\nd)\\n \\nControl narratives\\n \\ne)\\n \\nInterlocks/ ESD logic diagram\\n \\nf)\\n \\nEquipment layout diagram\\n \\ng)\\n \\nMaintenance and Inspection Data\\n \\nh)\\n \\nPlant historian data\\n \\n \\nT\\nh\\ne\\n \\nl\\ni\\ns\\nt\\n \\na\\nb\\no\\nve\\n \\nis\\n \\nn\\no\\nt\\n \\ne\\nx\\nh\\na\\nu\\nsti\\nv\\ne. Any\\n \\not\\nh\\ne\\nr\\n \\ndo\\nc\\nu\\nm\\ne\\nn\\nt\\ns\\n/ \\nd\\nr\\na\\nw\\nin\\ng\\ns\\n \\nreq\\nu\\nir\\ne\\nd\\n \\nf\\no\\nr\\n \\nt\\nhe \\nc\\nom\\np\\nletion\\n \\no\\nf the\\n \\nIPF\\n \\ns\\nt\\nu\\nd\\ny\\n \\ns\\nh\\na\\nll\\n \\nbe\\n \\nf\\nu\\nr\\nn\\nished\\n \\nas\\n \\na\\nn\\nd\\n \\nw\\nhen\\n \\nre\\nq\\nui\\nr\\ne\\nd\\n.\\n \\n")

subst = "\\1"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cx8rpV/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this solution can solve the mentioned cases, however I've a different case which is different from this, like below `\n3.1.4\\n \\nIPF\\n \\nc\\nla\\ns\\nsific\\na\\ntion\\n \\nte\\na\\nm\\n \\nThe\\n \\nt\\neam\\n \\np\\ne\\nr\\nf\\no\\nrming\\n \\nt\\nh\\ne\\n \\nI\\nP\\nF\\n \\nc\\nl\\na\\ns\\ns\\nif\\ni\\nc\\nat\\ni\\no\\nn\\n \\nshall\\n \\ncomprise the following\\n:\\n \\ni.\\n \\nP\\nrocess Technologists/ \\nProcess Engineer\\n \\nii.\\n \\nOperations shift leader or above`

Comment: however it can also happen in the middle of the string like `\\nE = Extensive impact\\n \\nThe recommended m\\nethod to achieve the consequences of failure on demand description is \\nas follows:\\n \\ni.\\n \\nDescribe the \\npurpose\\n \\n(or design intent) of the IPF;\\n \\nii.\\n \\nDescribe the \\ncause(s)of the demand on the IPF, the so called demand scenarios \\ni.e\\n.\\n \\nprocess control layer failure \\ne.g. con\\ntrol valve failure, \\nO\\nperator error, loss of \\nfeed` I'm thinking to include `:` into one of the condition, do you think this makes sense?

Comment: also I dont understand why you convert \n to \\n? isit compulsory? what if i want to keep as \n?

Comment: Thanks @Emma, I've improved and modified the regex and have posted the answer here. I only managed to extract whatever after the ':i.' hence i will continue to improvise from this so that I can include the explanation sentence before the roman idices subsection.

Answer (score 0):

After some exploration, below is the solution that produces the closest to what I'm looking to achieve:

```
regx = re.compile( ': \ni(?:(?!\n[A-Z]).).*?\.\n\d\.|:\ni(?:(?!\n[A-Z]).).*?\.\n\d\.',re.DOTALL)
find = str(cleanSectionContent2[req])
```

It detects those cases that start with ':i.' and end with the section header '\n\d.', but it cannot detect all cases, hence I will be updating more solution here.